# play audio using MediaExtractor, MediaCodec and AudioTrack

Tags: android, audiotrack, android-mediacodec

I would like to play streaming audio using `MediaExtractor`, `MediaCodec` and `AudioTrack`. I have used this [example](https://dpsm.wordpress.com/2012/07/28/android-mediacodec-decoded/). However it doesn't say how to create `AudioTrack`. I have tried this but I can only hear noise:

```
_audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 8000 /* 1 second buffer */,
                                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

Comment: I think you can find some good examples here: http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/media/tests/MediaFrameworkTest/src/com/android/mediaframeworktest/functional/audio/MediaAudioTrackTest.java#267 which should help you. Please do update if your issue is resolved or not.

Comment: Yes it's fine now. Thanks

Comment: If I may ask, what was the issue you had faced and how did you solve?

Comment: I only needed to use AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT instead of AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT. Thanks